# Variable outside local scope is not defined for test case

Tags: groovy

I wish to access outside variables for a test function that I am writing, in Groovy.

However, it doesn't seem that I can.

My code is like this:

```
Map<String, String> originalTableRowState = new HashMap<String, String>(),
    newTableRowState

// if there is table data to get, and do actions on
def WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
def List<WebElement> dataRows = driver.findElements(
    By.cssSelector('div.tab-pane.active .dataTables_scrollBody tbody tr:not(.dataTables_empty)'))   

'if there\'s table data, this test should run'
if (dataRows.size() > 0) {

    WebUI.comment('populate the tableRowState with the data from the first table row')
    fetchFirstRowDataInto(originalTableRowState)    

}


void fetchFirstRowDataInto(Map<String, String> tableRowState) { 
    List<WebElement> tableHeadings = driver.findElements(
        By.cssSelector('div.tab-pane.active .dataTables_scrollHead th'))
    WebElement firstRow = dataRows.get(0)
    List<WebElement> dataCells = firstRow.findElements(
        By.xpath('//td[not(@class="dataTables_empty") and not(*)]'))
    for (int i = 0; i < dataCells.size(); i++) {
        // save data to originalTableRowState with the table header text as the key
        tableRowState.put(tableHeadings.get(i), dataCells.get(i))
    }
}
```

and when I run it, it greets me with the error saying that `Variable 'driver' is not defined outside test case`. I just added the `def` keywords to the `driver`,`dataRows` definintions.

How to make `driver`,`dataRows` accessible inside functions, without passing them in as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the method variable-access issue by declaring it a JS-like closure:

/* change `void fetchFirstRowDataInto(Map<String, String> tableRowState) {` to `def fetchFirstRowDataInto = { Map<String, String> tableRowState  ->` */

and putting the definition **above** the invocation.

I welcome any better solutions...